# User-defined Vector class for python

Tags: python, vector, multidimensional-array, precision, performance

I've been looking for a way to deal with vectors in python and havent found a solution here or in the documentation that completely fits me.

This is what I've come up with so far for a vector class:

```
class vec(tuple):

    def __add__(self, y):
        if len(self)!=len(y):
            raise TypeError
        else:
            ret=[]
            for i,entry in enumerate(self):
                ret.append(entry+y[i])
            return vec(ret)

    def __mul__(self, y):
        t=y.__class__
        if t == int or t==float:
            #scalar multiplication
            ret=[]
            for entry in self:
                ret.append(y*entry)
            return vec(ret)
        elif t== list or t==tuple or t==vec:
            # dot product
            if len(y)!=len(self):
                print 'vecs dimensions dont fit'
                raise TypeError
            else:
                ret=0
                for i,entry in enumerate(self):
                    ret+=entry*y[i]
            return ret
```

Theres a little bit more, left out to keep things short. 
So far everythings working fine but I have lots of tiny specific questions (and will probably post more as they come up):

1. Are there base classes for the numeric and sequence-types and how can I address them?
2. How can I make all of this more Python-y? I want to learn how to write good Python code, so if you find something that's inefficient or just ugly, please tell me.
3. What about precision? As python seems to cast from integers to floats only if necessary, input and output are usually of the same type. So there might be problems with very large or small numbers, but I don't really need those currently. Should I generally worry about precision or does python do that for me? Would it be better to convert to the largest possible type automatically? Which one is that? What happens beyond that?

I want to use n-dimensional vectors in a project involving lots of vectorial equations and functions and I'd like to be able to use the usual notation that's used in math textbooks. As you can see this inherits from tuple (for easy construction, immutability and indexing) and most built in functions are overwritten in order to use the (+,-,*,..)- operators. They only work if the left operand is a vec (can I change that?). Multiplication includes dot- and scalar product, pow is also used for the cross-product if both vecs are 3D.

Test Script:

```
def testVec():
    rnd=random.Random()        
    for i in range(0,10000):
        a=utils.vec((rnd.random(),rnd.random(),rnd.random()))
        ### functions to test
        a*(a*a)           
        ###


def testNumpy():
    rnd=random.Random()        
    for i in range(0,10000):
        a=np.array((rnd.random(),rnd.random(),rnd.random()))
        ###
        a.dot(a)*a
        ###
cProfile.run('testNumpy()')
```

-> 50009 function calls in 0.135 seconds

```
cProfile.run('testVec()')
```

-> 100009 function calls in 0.064 seconds

Comment: http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/vector.html

Comment: Any reason you're not using NumPy?

Comment: NumPy is awesome. It'll beat anything you build yourself in speed, completeness, convenience, everything.

Comment: I'm currently using numpy.arrays but I found them kind of inconvenient to construct and operate on. I'd really like to use the dot/scalar-product and other shorthands for readability. I also tested both approaches using cProfiler on a script that produces several thousand 3D-vectors randomly and does some calculations with two or three of them at a time (which is quite close to what I need to do). The result was that numpy.arrays usually needed a lot (twice) longer for these operations. I don't know if that means anything though, because I have zero experience with cProfiler and numpy.

Comment: Is it really worth your time to do this for the sake of "readability"? `np.dot(a, b)` is pretty readable, and what you deem to be readable will likely be confusing to any other Python programmers. Also, I find it hard to believe that your code is faster than NumPy - would you post the script?

Comment: Ok I see that (my taste of) readability isn't really worth the effort. Also if its only for that i could probably use numpy.array as base class and add what I like.

Comment: I didnt expect the results of the test script either, but I can't find a mistake. It's about the same for all kinds of functions tested so far. By the way, how can I put 'testVec' and 'testNumpy' into one method?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your constructor in your class, but it seems that the speed difference is just down to time spent copying (or not copying) data when constructing the vectors. Move the `a =  ...` line outside the loop and see. Also try using `a=np.random.rand(3)`.

Comment: Increase the number of dimensions and NumPy becomes a lot faster (especially if you use the vectorised random function too)